# Can I set value to a member variable during a unit test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test

Firstly I request to not mark it as duplicate of [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282156/can-i-access-member-variable-of-method-of-a-class-under-test). It was incorrectly marked as duplicate and wrongly answered. Please read the question carefully and respond. Thanks..!!

So I want to access a member variable which has scope only inside the method which is to be tested during unit test of my controller class. So the code of my class to be tested looks like below(generic code as cannot post code online).

```
@Controller
public class testController(){

@Autowired
private Dependency dependency;

@RequestMapping("/SearchProject)
public String systemUnderTest(){
// some logic
Integer[] totalrecords = new Integer[1];
List<SomeObject> aList = dependency.someMethod(.,.,totalRecords,.,.);
//some logic
int value = Math.ceil(totalrecords[0]/CONSTANT_VALUE);
return "string";

}
```

What is happening is totalRecords[0] is set to a value inside someMethod() which I am already mocking in my test class so it remains null during my unit test run.

Is there any way I can access and set this 'totalRecords[0]' variable during my test ? Let me know if any more details are needed.

Comment: You can not modify or mock `totalrecords` since it's being initialized within the method to be tested.

Comment: Where is the value inserted into `totalrecords` in the actual code?

Comment: @MadhuBhat It will be inserted in someMethod() call as its reference is passed there.

Comment: Then can you remove the mock on `dependency` and let it go within the actual code and update `totalrecords`? That would be the only way, since you say that you cannot modify the code under test and `totalrecords` gets initialized within the same.

Comment: @MadhuBhat I have to mock the "dependency" coz the method goes into service layer which then further calls DAO layer and there it is initialized to a value.
Looks like I don't have any way to test this class without modifying the code which also isn't possible as its a legacy application and messing with source code will give nightmares  :(

Thanks for you help.

Comment: Your previous question, [Can I access member variable of method of a class under test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55282156/can-i-access-member-variable-of-method-of-a-class-under-test), was updated as a duplicate to a different solution which should work for you, hence this question now becomes a duplicate of the other :-). Summarizing again, use the `doAnswer` Mockito construct to update your `totalrecords` parameter with whatever value you need, instead of trying to access it via reflection (or something else) inside your class under test.